# Подключение сторонней библиотеки на CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, сборка, линковка

У меня есть библиотека с `CMakeLists.txt`  с таким кодом:

```
add_executable (run_OF_INT ${CODEFILES})
set_target_properties (run_OF_INT PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "SELECTMODE=1")
set_property(TARGET run_OF_INT APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "SELECTCHANNEL=1") # use grey-valued image
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(run_OF_INT ${OpenCV_LIBS})

add_executable (run_OF_RGB ${CODEFILES})
set_target_properties (run_OF_RGB PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "SELECTMODE=1")
set_property(TARGET run_OF_RGB APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "SELECTCHANNEL=3") # use RGB image
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(run_OF_RGB ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Все это один проект, но, как видно, запускается с разными параметрами.
Вопрос в том, как я могу включить эту библиотеку в свою?

Мне хочется сделать что-то вроде

```
#include(run_OF_INT)
```

И дальше использовать методы, сконфигурированные под `run_OF_INT`.
Также вопрос по поводу конфликтов. Если я сделаю, что-то вроде

```
#include(run_OF_INT)
#include(run_OF_RGB)
```

Не будет ли проблем?

Мой проект также на CMake.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста "У меня есть библиотека с CMakeLists.txt с таким кодом:" - она создана Вами или Вы её используете и менять не можете?

Answer (score 0):

1

```
add_executable (run_OF_RGB ${CODEFILES})
```

Это не библиотека а исполняемый файл (elf или exe)

Makefile для библиотеки собирается через

```
add_library(${LIBNAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

2
По сути вопроса

Лично я для себя пишу Find${LIBNAME}.cmake файлы и дальше просто вызываю find_package - 
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html

```
...
find_package(${LIBNAME})
include_directories(${${LIBNAME}_INCLUDE_DIR})
....
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBNAME})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${LINUXRANDOM_INCLUDE_DIR}/${LIBNAME})
```

Comment: Что будет происходить после этих действий? Каким образом я смогу задать эти настройки?
```set_target_properties (run_OF_RGB PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "SELECTMODE=1")
set_property(TARGET run_OF_RGB APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "SELECTCHANNEL=3")```

Comment: @he11boy Уважаемый коллега, главный навык хорошего программиста - уметь правильно читать и гуглить. Очень хорошего программиста, уметь читать маны и понимать что гуглить. см. https://cmake.org/